# Handing out 4 different exams to n students, such that no adjacent pair shares the same exam.

Tags: combinatorics

$ n $ students are sitting on a circular table, solving an exam. There are 4 versions of the exam.
If $ n \ge 2 $, in how many ways can the exams be handed out, such that no two students that sit next to each other have the same version?

How can I solve this using the I-E principle?

Edit: this is my thought process:

Let's say I have placed $ n - 1 $ students in a circle that satisfies the conditions. Then, for placing the $n$-th student, I have two options: the exams that are NOT the exams of the student to the left, and to the right.

That gives: $ f(n) = 2f(n-1) $.
However, $f(0) = 1 $, $ f(1) = 4 $, and $ f(2) = 12 $. That does not match my RR...

For the I-E principle, I want to define a "bad" event, meaning, $ A_i = $ "the students  $(i, i + 1) $ have the same exam", and I want to find $\bigcap_{i=1}^kA_i^c $.

So if we pick $k$ students that are having the same exam, we can treat those $k$ students as one student, and so we have $4^{n-k} $ options for the rest, and $ 4 $ options for the $k$ students, so $ 4^n \cdot 4^{-k} \cdot 4^1 = 4^{n-k+1} $ options, and that is my $\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i $.

I don't know how to figure out the correct RR/using I-E.

Comment: With regard to using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, what have you tried?  With regard to your recurrence relation, how did you obtain it and what are your initial conditions?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sorry for the trouble. I've edited my post.

Comment: What makes this problem tricky is that if you have at least four students, the first student and the $(n - 1)$st student may or may not have the same version of the examination.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are $k+1$ exams ($k>0$). Let choose a first student and give him a certain exam. Now we distribute the exams among the rest $n-1$ students to obtain an allowed distribution of the exams. Let the number of such distributions be $J_k(n)$.

If we follow the rule that the **right** neighbor of a student (starting with the first one) obtains a different exam the overall number of distributions would be $k^{n-1}$. However among these distributions there will be such ones that the first student and his **left** neighbor have the same exam. The number of such wrong distributions is obviously $J_k(n-1)$.

Thus
$$J_k(n)=k^{n-1}-J_k(n-1)$$
with $J_k(2)=k$, or
$$
J_k(n)=k^{n-1}-k^{n-2}+k^{n-3}-\cdots +(-1)^{n}k=\frac{k^n+(-1)^nk}{k+1}.
$$

Since we could give the first student any of $k+1$ exams the final answer is:
$$
(k+1)J_k(n)=k^n+(-1)^nk.
$$